# Can't in remove gap between top and header

Tags: html, css

I have few css i can't remove strange space between top and header.

**container.css**

```
display: table;
height: 100%;
```

Inside i have

**header.css**

```
text-align: center;
width: 90%;
padding: 0px;
```

And that's how it looks [image]

Setting padding and margin to 0 is not working for some reasons.

Only one way to move header that i found is changing

```
margin-top: 0px;
```

Bug it doesn't change until i change to -22.

If i change it to -23(exactly -23) then it moves out of page like this :

[image]

Can someone help find the reason?
Thank you for assistance.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/apimenov93/vj3yp0nf/) - try to change margin-top of header

Comment: do you have a lilnk to the actual site or is this something local we can't see?

Comment: it's local, i will try to make a fiddle

Comment: which container is the problem?

Comment: i added fiddle, problem with header

Comment: Haha- border is 10px. remove it from `.main-box`.

Comment: it doesn't help, still same behaviour

Comment: use `position:absolute` in ur `.main-box` it should be able to help.

Comment: check the fiddle here, it's border issue - https://jsfiddle.net/1uzy9h5t/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your menu and your content are treated as table-cells. Add

```
.main-box { vertical-align: top; }
```

to your CSS to get rid of the auto margin.

Comment: Well, that being fixed I have to add, that this is not the best way to style your website. But that's another problem.

Comment: what do you mean? :)

Comment: Using tables (or disguising div elements as table elements) just for the design of a web page is generally thought of as being very low standard. There are a lot of tools to create the same setup in a different way.

Comment: That's really a broad topic. I would suggest to read about HTML5 and semantic web tags like `<nav>` and `<section>` as well as responsive grid layouts. You can google both and will find tons of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css

```
vertical-align: top;
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML some elements come with their own margin and padding.
To remove this default margin, padding we should "reset css".

Add following code in your css

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Check if it helps :)

star (*) is universal selector. It'll reset all elements margin and padding.